# How to find bytecodes of matches?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, search

I do have a bytecode string and start and end indices in bytecodes of all matches (from a texteditor).

example `mystring`:

```
a few names with accents are Emily Brontë, Noël Coward, Zoë Wanamaker
```

When I do a search of words that contain an `ë` I find these (bytecode) indices in my texteditor:
`matches = [[35, 43], [44, 49], [58, 62]]`

Now I want to search within these matches using python p.e. to find all substrings of the letter `o` and find the new bytecodes of these `o` in `mystring`.

```
newmatches = []
     for n in matches:
         for m in reg.finditer(str(mystring[n[0]:n[1]], 'utf-8')):
             newmatches.append([m.start(), m.end()])
```

In above example start() and end() are not bytecodes and are not indices within `mystring` but indices in the substring.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: When you say "...and find the new bytecodes of these `o` in `mystring`", you're referring to the *indices* of the new bytecodes, correct?

Comment: @Marathon55, yes sorry that I did not make myself clear

Comment: Your byte counts are not entirely convincing. Mind adding your text match expression to your question, so we can replicate your results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have your `matches` array, do a second search on `mystring` where you find the indices of `o` (let's call this new array `o_matches`). Then loop through the items in `o_matches` -- if the item is contained in any of your intervals in your `matches` array, then add it to `newmatches`, because that means it is part of of a word that contains an accent.

Comment: Thank you Marathon55, that's a good idea! However I still do have the problem that my texteditor gives the indices in bytecodes (binary), python (finditer()) search on string (not binary).

Comment: Can you show the code you used to get your `matches` array?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because the code is in vimscript (vim editor).

Comment: Can you also search `mystring` for indices of the character `o` using vim, and then pass both arrays (`matches` and `o_matches`) to python to perform logic on?

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. It resolved my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To get the indices within `mystring` instead of the indices in the substring, you'll want to add the value of `n[0]` to both start() and end().

Comment: It doesn't work because finditer() doesn't find bytecodes